# Tomcat stops responding after few days without getting crashed

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Production issue where tomcat stops responding after a few days.
Below are my observations:

1. The tomcat application was under continuous load.
2. Allocated Heap is 1024Mb and *PermGen* 512 Mb
3. Tomcat process consumed 2.75Gb of Memory.
4. Total Memory(Machine) is 4Gb and other process are also running like jmxTranse and other monitoring tools so total consumed memory by all processes is 3656mb out of 3764mb total memory.
5. We are also using our native library calls on the server.

My questions are:

1. How to debug the actual cause of tomcat hanging?
2. How to debug if the memory consumption is caused by Native calls?

Please let me know if Heap state needs to be posted.

Comment: Did you analyzed the heap dump?

Comment: Is application using any database?

Comment: @underdog yes i analysed heap dump and heap state both but nothing nasty there.

Comment: @Ankit yes we are using mysql database.

Comment: Sometimes this problem comes because of database connections leakages. So check your database connections, you might forget to close few connections after use.

Comment: @AnkitSharma No there is not any connection leak or memory leak of objects as i have analyzed heap dump.

Comment: @user2139372 were you able to solve this issue? What was causing this? please share